# Unable to import upickle with Scalajs-react shared dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, scala.js, scalajs-react, upickle

i have a small problem. I am trying to use upickle lib. i have included it in my sharedDependencies as "com.lihaoyi" %%% "upickle" % "0.3.6". For some reason i am able to import upickle in my server project but it is still not available in my client project. I am trying to understand what is it i am doing wrong. I am following scala-react-spa tutorial [here](https://github.com/ochrons/scalajs-spa-tutorial)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not available", exactly? What is the error message and where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was offline for few days.By not available i meant i was not able to import lib. Idea just gave me `Compilation error[not found: object upickle]` I just imported new project from existing sources and it worked for me. It must some issue related to indexing in Intellij-idea.

Comment: @ShubhamKamthania Could you post an answer here yourself and clarify that having it in the shared project is the correct answer? I think you can accept your own answer as well. Just to make it easier for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to answer this question. This is a problem related to indexing intellij-idea. Many a times idea just fail to index properly or fails to import sbt project. So two options that can possibly works is to go to file > invalidate cache and restart or import the project again as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937328/intellij-idea-cannot-import-sbt-project). Sorry for chipping in late for this one.

**Edit 1**

Here is more details from the above link to add more description to the answer

```
On the right-hand side of your IntelliJ window, you will see a list of vertical tabs, open the SBT tab.
Select the module that's causing trouble, right click on it, select "Detach external project"
Try to import the module again.
```

Comment: Try to put more description in answer rather than linking to another question.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [example build.sbt with upickle](https://github.com/hussachai/play-scalajs-showcase/blob/master/build.sbt).
You don't need upickle in shared project.
Instead you need it in server as

```
"com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % <latestVersion>
```

and in client as

```
"com.lihaoyi" %%% "upickle" % <latestVersion>
```

Make sure you used 2 percent signs in server and 3 in client.

Comment: According to OP, having it in the shared project actually worked (after an IDE reindex). That's what I'm doing myself as well.